# Automatic screenshots for shell tutorial

Tags: bash, shell, screenshot

I'm working on a small bash tutorial for a programming course. I would like to alternate between explanations for the commands and images as below

---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
[image: First image]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
[image: Second image]

---

I would like to automatically generate these images given a list of commands as doing it manually would be very tedious. Going from a screenshot to a cropped image is the easy part, I'm looking for solutions for the "commands => screenshots" part.

For example, these two images could be generated from the following "instructions" :

```
clear
ls
saveas "img1.png"

clear
mkdir example
ls
saveas "img2.png"
```

I've looked at http://ascii.io/docs/about and I was thinking of using a similar technique : a python script would be reading the "instructions" and feed them to a subprocessed shell and would be calling a screenshot utility when needed.

Am I trying to reinvent the wheel ? Is there a tool that could be used to generate these kind of images ? Or a simplest way to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick's `import` can be used to capture window images using `-window`. Simply hide the menu, toolbar, tabbar, and scrollbar in the terminal before using. Use `xwininfo(1)` to get the window ID.

```
$ import -window 0x145cba2 terminal.png
```

[image: terminal.png]

Comment: I would still need to type the commands, that's the part I would like to automatize (let's say I have about 100-200 commands in total) by a script that would automatically re-generate all the images.

Comment: You could try shoving it into `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.